# How to compute $\text{liminf}\frac{ \varphi(2^n-1)}{2^n}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $\varphi$ denote Euler's function. How can I compute $\liminf_n \frac{\varphi(2^n-1)}{2^n}$?

Comment: @HenryW.: the lower bound you mentioned shows that $liminf_n \varphi(n)/n=0$. not sure if that helps me.

Comment: Assuming that there are infinitely many even perfect numbers (or infinitely many Mersenne primes, if you will), the value of this sequence goes between $\frac12$ and $1$ (hence the limit does not exist).

Comment: @barakmanos: I'm asking for liminf.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$?

Comment: @barakmanos No, lim inf is perfectly well-defined for this sequence.  What are you confused about?

Comment: @ErickWong: The answer to `What are you confused about` is given one comment above yours.

Comment: @adrido The key here is to note that almost any prime can occur as a divisor of $2^n-1$ provided you take $n$ to be highly composite.

Comment: @barakmanos I don't catch your meaning.  The question is clearly about a lim inf, but you keep asking about the limit.

Comment: @ErickWong: I don't keep asking about anything. I made a comment under the assumption that OP meant $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$, that's all (I just find it odd that you don't understand my confusion, based on that assumption).

Comment: @ErickWong: you seem to be suggesting that the answer is 0. could you elaborate? how do you factor 2^n-1 for highly composite n? I tried $n=p_1...p_k$ (the product of the first k primes), but I can't find factors other than $2^{p_k}-1$

Comment: @barakmanos Why would OP be asking about the limit when it is explicitly stated **three** times that it is a lim inf, and the lim inf version of the problem is more interesting?

Comment: @adrido Yup, I believe the answer is $0$.  It's easier to look at it in reverse: take an odd prime $p$ and show that $p \mid 2^k-1$ for some $k$.  Then we also have $p \mid 2^n-1$ provided $n$ is a multiple of $k$.  If $n$ is a multiple of many such values of $k$ then...

Comment: @ErickWong: I see two times in the post, and the second one could just as well be a copy-paste mistake of the first one (obviously, it is not, but this is how I interpreted it when I read the question).

Comment: @barakmanos The third time is in the comments (actually there is a fourth, sorry).  Please pay attention to the people you are trying to get corrections from :).

Comment: @ErickWong: thanks! I believe that works.

Comment: @adrido have you any difficulty with my proof?

Comment: @2000: No, I think it's a nice proof but I need to first understand the theorem you are quoting before I can understand your proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If $p_1,...,p_k$ are **some** distinct prime divisors of $n$, then $\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}\leq \frac{(p_1-1)(p_2-1)...(p_k-1)}{p_1p_2...p_k}$. For the proof see [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)
2. $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb R >0 \quad \exists k\in \mathbb N \quad \text{s.t}\quad \frac{(p_1-1)(p_2-1)...(p_k-1)}{p_1p_2...p_k}<\epsilon$ when $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number. Because $\infty=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-1}}=\frac{1}{\frac{(p_1-1)(p_2-1)...}{p_1p_2...}}$
   You can see [Divergence of the sum of the reciprocals of the primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes)
3. If $a|b$ then $2^a-1|2^b-1$
4. By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) $p_i|2^{p_i-1}-1$ for all $1\leq i \leq k$

If we set $n=(p_1-1)(p_2-1)...(p_k-1)$ then by 3 and 4 we can conclude $p_i|2^n-1$

Thus by 1 $$ \frac{\varphi(2^n-1)}{2^n-1}<\varepsilon$$

and by 2 $$\liminf_n \frac{ \varphi(2^n-1)}{2^n}=0$$

Comment: what do you mean by there are infinitely many primes in $2^n-1$?

Comment: @adrido I added more details.

Comment: @2000 : The infinitude of Mersenne primes is conjectured, not proven.

Comment: @learner primes  **as divisor** not itself prime , by step 1.

Comment: @learner I edited my question.